# Javascript создать несколько объектов по одному конструктору с данными json

Tags: javascript, json, ооп

Есть задание по учебе. Создать сайт с новостями, новости должны выводиться по категориям, данные в файле JSON.

```
{
    "news":[
        {"category":"x",
            "title":"x",
            "image":"x",
            "text":"x",
            "author":"x",
            "link":"x"},

        {"category":"y",
            "title":"y",
            "image":"y",
            "text":"y",
            "author":"y",
            "link":"y"},

                {"category":"x",
            "title":"x",
            "image":"x",
            "text":"x",
            "author":"x",
            "link":"x"},

        {"category":"y",
            "title":"y",
            "image":"y",
            "text":"y",
            "author":"y",
            "link":"y"}
}]
}
```

Это json файл.
Получается, есть две категории, и новости из одной должны выводиться под одним подзаголовком, а второй - под другим подзаголовком.

На основе данных создается конструктор. И я понимаю как создать один объект, но как создать множество объектов из одного файла, и какую технологию использовать - не понимаю.

Расскажите пожалуйста хотя бы где искать, потому что все, что я нашла по json  - это как создать только один объект.

Comment: То что Вы привели - это уже массив объектов. Что еще Вам нужно и зачем конструктор?

Comment: Мне нужно вывести его в браузере по категориям. Как это сделать?